# smart counter by mooc

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to solve this exercise for a couple of days now but cant do it. In this exercise two `ArrayLists` have a list of integers. The integers that is contained in each list have to be removed and number that are not identical should be displayed in one `ArrayList` (lets say `arrayList1` merged with `arrayList2`). I only want to use `foreach` loop. No changes are to be made in the main. Changes requested only in the method.

```
public class SmartCombining {
    public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        int index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        for (int number : list1) {
            for (int num2 : list2) {
                if (list2.contains(number) == list1.contains(num2)) {
                    list2.remove(index2);
                    list1.remove(index);                    
                }
                index2++;
            }
            index++;
        }
        list1.addAll(list2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
        Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);

        // Remove comment when method ready
        // smartCombine(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us [mcve] which is problem decription, example input, expected output and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave `list1` untouched and just modify `list2` by removing those elements that are common to `list1` and adding those that are in `list1` but not in `list2`. Before you exit the `smartCombine` method you could add `list2` to `list1` to obtain the union between the lists and `list2` will contain the symmetric difference i.e. the elements that are not in both lists.

```
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
    for(Integer i : list1) {
        if(list2.contains(i)) {
            list2.remove(i);
        } else {
            list2.add(i);
        }
    }
    // if you don't need the union, don't add the line below and
    // list1 will contain [4, 3] otherwise it will contain [4, 3, 5, 10, 7]
    list1.addAll(list2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
    Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);

    // Remove comment when method ready
    smartCombine(list1, list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
    System.out.println(list2);

    // list1 will the contain the union of both lists [4, 3, 5, 10, 7]
    // list2 will have symmetric difference [5, 10, 7]
}
```

Comment: well this didn't solve the question since the numbers didnt get removed from list 2. secondly the common numbers have to be removed from both lists, not just list 2.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: This means that the method adds a new number to the list only if the list does not already contain that number. You might find the method contains from the ArrayList class useful. You can use that method to check if a number is in the list.

now the only error that i am getting after your code is this:


Combination of lists [5, 1, 2] and [5, 1, 2, 1, 40] has twice the number 1.

Comment: i also removed out the else statement from your code by the way... if i didnt remove it, i am getting two errors. the other error thati get is: Combination of lists [10, 11] and [5] has twice the number 0.

Comment: i cleared it, only one word did the magic. replacing if with while :D

Comment: thanks for your help... it made me learn something about for each loop on how to use it...

Comment: @user2138756 Ok I'm glad I was able to help somehow and that you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SmartCombining {

    public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer number : list1) {
            while (list2.contains(number)) {
                    list2.remove(number);                
            } 
        }

        list1.addAll(list2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
        Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);

        // Remove comment when method ready
        // smartCombine(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }
}
```